# Как открыть несколько div-ов, закрывая старые?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется код.

```js
var show;

function viewdiv(id) {
  param = document.getElementById(id);
  if (param.style.display == "none") {
    if (show) show.style.display = "none";
    param.style.display = "block";
    show = param;
  } else param.style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv');"> блок 1</a>
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv2');"> блок 2</a>
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv3');"> блок</a>

      <div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv');viewdiv('mydiv2');"> VSE </a>


        <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;"> text 1</div>
        <div id="mydiv2" style="display:none;"> text 2</div>
        <div id="mydiv3" style="display:none;"> tЕЕ</div>
```

Нужно. Что бы при нажатие на кнопку vse открывался первый и второй div. (на данный момент он открывает последний)
Самое главное что бы при этом сохранилось закрывание старых div-ов

https://jsfiddle.net/Vovan6996/p75L064r/19

Comment: Уточните, что имеете ввиду - "Самое главное что бы при этом сохранилось закрывание старых div-ов"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил всем дивам класс, для их идентификации, ну и прятал бы их тоже с помощью класса, и в функцию передавать не один ид а массив, выглядеть будет примерно так :

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-div')

function viewdiv(...ids) {
  divs.forEach(div => div.classList.toggle('invisible', !~ids.indexOf(div.id)))
}
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv')"> блок 1</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv2')"> блок 2</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv3')"> блок</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv', 'mydiv2')"> VSE </a><br/>

<div id="mydiv" class="my-div invisible"> text 1</div>
<div id="mydiv2" class="my-div invisible"> text 2</div>
<div id="mydiv3" class="my-div invisible"> tЕЕ</div>
```